convergence of almost supermartingales to a bounded set
Let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real-valued random variables adapted to $\{F_n\}$. Let $\{T_n \in (0, 1)\}$ be a sequence of strictly decreasing deterministic real numbers. Suppose it holds that
$$E[z_{n+1} | F_n] \leq (1 - T_n) z_n + T_n.$$
If we additionally know that $\sum T_n < \infty$, a classical result from Robbins and Siegmund can be used to prove that $z_n$ converges to a finite limit almost surely. However, if we have $\sum_n T_n = \infty$, can we at least show that $\lim\sup_n z_n < C$ almost surely for some finite constant $C$? I tried to extend the proof of Robbins and Siegmund and Doob's upcrossing lemma but had no luck. It's ok to add some additional assumptions, e.g., uniformly bounded second moments.
